# In what circumstances is onRenderBody not run?

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I have a `gatsby-ssr.js` with an `onRenderBody` that doesn't get run during `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build`.

repro: https://github.com/GraphQLGuide/book/tree/repro-no-ssr

`ON FILE LOAD` is printed during `gatsby build`, but `ON RENDER BODY` isn't: [gatsby-ssr.js](https://github.com/GraphQLGuide/book/blob/repro-no-ssr/gatsby-ssr.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried ES6 notation?

Instead of :

```
exports.onRenderBody = (
  { setHeadComponents, pathname = `/` },
  { crossOrigin = `anonymous` } = {}
) => {
```

Do:

```
import React from "react"

export const onRenderBody = (
    { setHeadComponents, pathname = `/` },
    { crossOrigin = `anonymous` } = {}
) => {
```

It seems that some webpack versions prevent the triggering of some SSR functions.

Interesting/related threads:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4718